# Plesk is delivering incorrect SSL certificate when accessed through OpenSSL cli, but correct in browser

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a Plesk setup with several sites. When accessed in the browser, Plesk serves the proper SSl cert just fine.

But then when I go to access it through openssl using

```
openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443
```

I get a different sites SSL back. It is another site on the server, but not the one for that domain.

This is the error I'm getting when using that openssl call.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.example.com
i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.go
daddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=
---
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple sites using separate SSL certificates, there's an SSL extension called SNI that allows the client and the server to negotiate which hostname should be verified.

In order for s_client to use SNI you need to specify it on the command line with the option  `-servername`.

Example:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername www.example.com
```

Comment: This is giving me: unknown option -servername

Comment: then your openssl is too old

Comment: What openssl version are you using? This has been around for at least a couple of years.

Comment: Interesting. The OpenSSL version that comes with the Git install for Windows is incredibly old. OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007. Switched to my Mac and this solution worked perfectly.